# Having an acronym for a villainous organization

Tags: novel, acronyms

I have this organization in my working book called NOVA.

And it means National Occupation Variation Association.

they basically take people from their homes and families and force them to work on re-building the world. pretty much killing the ones that don't want to work.

Is it appropriate to use NOVA, since it's a popular organization name in many novels and Movies.

Comment: Is your book set on our Earth?

Comment: mostly, yes. sometimes its on another planet

Comment: How many other options have you played with? Is there any double entendre elements, like NOVA causes some sort of explosions or something? anything? If you have a reason for NOVA definitely keep it, but if it is coincidental maybe play with other options?

Comment: They play a big part in the plot.

Comment: Nova is appropriate for rebuilding. If they make a point not to just re-build the old, but to replace the old with new and improved. Not to re-build the old world, but to create a new one. But the name seems awkward. I'd just use something suitably bureaucratic like "**N**ational **O**rganization of **V**olunteer **A**ssociations", or something. National Organized Volunteers Authority? Anyway, I think an organization like that would want to stress that everybody is a volunteer. Nobody who refused is working for them. (Or even breathing...)

Answer (score 1):

I think what your asking is because you have mentioned

> many novels and movies

If you’re worried if the name NOVA will be a cliche for being a common name .
As long as you state their goal and what they do and whether they’re antagonists or well-intentioned people, you will be fine

Answer (score 1):

I didn't immediately think "Ah. That's from [insert name]", so I'd think it was either common enough to be regarded as generic, or niche enough that no one has really claimed it as their own. (I would have reacted differently if you were asking about SPECTRE or HYDRA).

It might be that other posters here have heard of a Big Name where it's been used, but at the moment I think you're fine using it.

One thought, though : you mention "rebuilding the world", but the "N" stands for "National". Does the organisation not span the world, or is each part of the group looking at specific countries? It's entirely possible I'm seeing a problem that isn't there, but if the organsation is international, I'm unlikely to be the last person to wonder about this.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it is used by several entities makes it public domain, if that is what you are worried about. There is nobody that "owns" the acronym if it is used by many independent entities.

+1 to ItWasLikeThat: National does not equal World, or Worlds. You might want to look through a dictionary for some other word starting with N, like "Necessary".

Comment: Okay, I'll be more mindful of that next time. Thank you